# Job On Sql Server Agent does not complete, but it does in BIDS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, dts

My package works like a treat in SSIS ( BIDS ) and executes in 4 minutes . Logging onto integrations services in SQL Server management studio and importing it into file system or stored packages and then running it, again takes 6 minutes .

Now moving it to SQL Server Agent . It runs and runs .... Looks like when it comes to a few tasks that mean running a bat file to open an excel file then a vbs file to run a few macros it seems it cannot cope with it . I worked this out using sql server profiler . Killed the job after 40 mins and no meaningful errors . Even looked at the Windows NT logs !

I need to get this package working on sql server agent so it is automated and I can schedule it to run a few times every day .

Can anyone help me resolve this as I am stuck ?

SQL Server User / Credentials / proxy Account has been set up correctly and earlier in the control flow it does run another bat file which copies across a file to another directory .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because SQL Server Agent does not load a user's environment to be able to run Excel macros. You need to schedule Excel macros via the Windows Scheduler (and log in at least once to clear the Excel licensing little pop-ups that come up).