# SQL job failed to run a C#.net console application

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, vba

I have a simple excel file that has the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

I tried to run a sql job to open this excel file but it failed, became unresponsive. On googling, I found the reason 'why' SQL job wouldn't open excel file
[Job On Sql Server Agent does not complete, but it does in BIDS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745626/job-on-sql-server-agent-does-not-complete-but-it-does-in-bids)

So I thought of creating a simple console application in C# which would simply open the excel file and run my macro. Here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Threading;


namespace T_OpenExcel
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        //Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\data_extracts\TestHelloWorld.xlsm", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        RunMacro(xlWorkBook, new Object[] { "TestHello" });


        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
    }

    private static void RunMacro(Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook, object[] p)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

I could successfully run this code in IDE. Now I want to run this from SQL job in SSMS, sql server 2008.

I grabbed T_OpenExcel.exe file from my C# project( T_OpenExcel-->bin-->Debug-->T_OpenExcel.exe). I created a SQL Job.Here are some of my details:

Step name: OpenHelloWorldExcel
Type:Operating system(CmdExec)
Run as: SQL Server Agent Service Account
Command: C:\Users\shress2\Documents\visual studio 2010\projects\T_OpenExcel\T_OpenExcel\bin\Debug\T_OpenExcel.exe

On running this job, I get the following status
Start Job 'TestHelloWorld' Status Success
Execute job 'TestHelloWorld' Status Error

On viewing history, it shows:
Message
Executed as user: GSOPS4\SYSTEM. Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'E:\data_extracts\TestHelloWorld.xlsm'. 
There are several possible reasons:
     The file name or path does not exist. 
     The file is being used by another program. 
     The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.     at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)     at T_OpenExcel.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\shress2\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\T_OpenExcel\T_OpenExcel\Program.cs:line 23.  Process Exit Code -532462766.  The step failed.

I checked E:\data_extracts\TestHelloWorld.xlsm directory and found it working. I made sure my xlsm file is not being used by anyone. I couldn't figure out why its failing to run it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in adv!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you're attempting to show a messagebox while opening the Excel file, but you're automating it, so there's no human to click the button on the messagebox.  The rest of the code can't execute because the file is sitting there waiting for someone to click the button.

On subsequent runs, the server can't access it because it's still sitting there, invisible to normal users, waiting for the button to be clicked.  hence the errors.

Short version: Don't proompt for user input on an app that will be run unattended.

Comment: Thanks for your input. i will try something with my macro- that doesn't require human intervention. Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, I modified my macro to rename sheet1 to RenameSheet1 for simplicity. When I run my project from IDE, it prompted me Excel SaveAs window, requiring my input. I tried to do SaveAs in my code xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(@"E:\data_extracts\RenameSheets21.xlsm"); before closing and quitting. But Everytime i run the project, I keep getting SaveAs prompt. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: I seldom work with Excel, but if I remember correectly, the SaveAs funciton has an overload that takes a boolean value to specify whether it is supposed to overwrite the file if it exists. While I'm digging up my code to see if that's right, you could try that.

Comment: Nope.  My code doesn't have anything that allows us to overwrite an existing Excel file. I DO have code that deleted the file if it exists before savings, so maybe that was my workaround, but it probably also depends on the vversion of Excel you're trying to automate.  You could try doing something to ensure the filename is unique before saving.. Like use System.Guid.NewId and name the file System.Guid.NewId().ToString() + ".xls";  If you can get away from it promnpting you should be golden. Good luck!

Comment: Hi David, I used SaveAs with correct args to by pass SaveAs prompt that was seen before. my Project runs fine in IDE. But when I tryo to run it from SQL Job, it fails for the same reason(in my first post). I don't know why it would fail while running it from SQL Job. Please let me know. Thanks.